# Sharing variables between different files in a plugin

Tags: variables

Supposing I have two scripts that share variables. What is the preferred way to do this, supposing I wanted to keep the variables only in one place? Is there a way to keep them script-local and not global?

---

Context: I'm writing two [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/) syntax checkers that both the same errorformat (because underneath they use the same compiler). What would be the preferred way to share an `errorformat` variable between the two files of these syntax checkers?

I was later [explained](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/pull/1772#issuecomment-219706885) by the maintainer that since these variables aren't meant to be changed often, I should just have them in two places. This question is still here because the how-to question is still answerable, although it is no longer relevant in the original context.

Comment: The preferred way would be to leave the two copies alone.  The `errorformat` shouldn't change more often than once in a few years, so who cares.  Trying to make it "shared" creates a problem instead of solving one.  If you use a global variable, you need to make sure it's initialised before either checker gets to run.  If you use a common include you're writing more code than you're avoiding.

Comment: It's a misleading question.  The solution for your particular setup is not the solution that should be used "in general".

Comment: @lcd047 you are quite right, I rewrote the question to separate the actual question and the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a global variable:

```
:h global-variable

                    *global-variable* *g:var* *g:*
Inside functions global variables are accessed with "g:".  Omitting this will
access a variable local to a function.  But "g:" can also be used in any other
place if you like.
```

You can use it as follow:

```
let g:my_variable = 1
```

And then `g:my_variable` is accessible from anywhere within vim and plugins.

Comment: So there is no way to limit the scope to those files that need it?

Comment: mh not that I can think of, but you should see `:h internal-variables` to see all options for variable scoping.